# Landing in hidden city, coming back from "official" city: is it possible?

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines, hidden-city-ticketing

Let's suppose someone (who's definitely not me...) wants to go to Colombia to know many cities. This fictional character will buy a ticket from São Paulo, Brasil to Barranquilla, Colombia (to go and to come back). This flight has a stop in Bogotá before its final destination.

Then, once in Bogotá, this person suddently decides to know Bogotá and she/he leaves his/her flight and then this person will arrive in Barranquilla to get his/her flight in its scheduled date.

The question is: would the flight company crew accept this person? I mean, this character could get this flight and come back to São Paulo without any problem?

Comment: No, that's exactly the thing that you can't do (and almost every guide on hidden cities says).

Comment: @CMaster That's an answer.